# How to send notifications in VirtoCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtocommerce

I'm working with VirtoCommerce API. I've set up everything locally. however when I call virtocommerce API I get the following:

[image]
It seems some APIs work, some don't. This user exists in DB (AspNetUser table)
How would one send an email invite using VirtoCommerce API?

Comment: there is no code..i'm calling existing VirtoCommerce API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several points to note:

1. You should run Virto Commerce from local IIS. Check "Configure IIS"
   chapter in https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/deployment/platform-deployment/deploy-from-source-code
2. "api/storefront/security" controller is deprecated, consider using
   "users/{loginOrEmail}/requestpasswordreset" from Platform instead.
3. Why don't you try Swagger UI https://admin-demo.virtocommerce.com/docs/ui/index#/VirtoCommerce%20platform/Security_RequestPasswordReset?